# Convert String="one,two,three" to String='one','two','three'

Tags: java, mysql, string, hibernate

Need to convert my String values "one,two,three" to 'one','two','three'
I have below code

`String input = "One,two,three";`

Need to send this input values for an query in hibernate.

So need to send as 'one','two','three' as single string, please provide me a solution easy way to do it

Comment: `replace(",","','")` and surround the result with another `'`.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
String result = input.replace(",", "','").replaceAll("(.*)", "'$1'");
```

- `input.replace(",", "','")` replaces each `,` with `','` so at this step your string will look like:

  One','two','three
- next we use a regex to surround the string with `'`, now it'll look

  'One','two','three'

which is what you want.

Regex explanation: We catch the whole string, then we replace it with itself, but surrounded with single quote.

References:

- [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)
- [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using regex :

```
input.replaceAll("(\\w+)", "\'$1\'")
```

In regex, 'w' is the word character.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: ++ but you don't need to add new group, we already have group 0 which represents entire match. Also it would be probably better to use `[^,]` instead of `\w`.

Answer (score -2):

```
String[] split = input.split(",");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0 ; i < split.length ; i++ ) {
   sb.append("'" + str + "'");
   if ( i != split.length-1 ) {
      sb.append(",");
   }
}



sb.toString();


not smart, but easiest..
```